# SQL - Adding each value to every other value in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a sample table

```
table
2
4
6
```

I want to add each value to every other value in this manner:

```
table
(2+2)
(2+4)
(2+6)
(4+2)
(4+4)
(4+6)
(6+2)
(6+4)
(6+6)
```

The end result should look like:

```
table
4 
6 
8 
6 
8 
10
8 
10
12
```

But I have no idea on how to calculate all the values in this manner.

Comment: which dbms?????

Comment: @eray postgresql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a self `CROSS JOIN` to get a cross product:

```
select t1.c + t2.c
from tablename t1 cross join tablename t2
```

Add `ORDER BY` if you need to guarantee that specific order:

```
ORDER BY t1.c, t2.c
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! Appreciate ya